# phpMyadmin is not working on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

I need to login into phpmyadmin through browser.

The problem I am having when I pass url http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php, phpmyadmin ask for password & user name then on submit page refreshes, & token assigned  by phpmyadmin changes.

Strange thing is that I can access my database through terminal

```
mysql -u root -p.
```

Works fine but I cannot dig logs in apache

```
tail -f /va/logs/apache2
```

no errors in  logs.

How to get logs of mysql & phpmyadmin.

I have tried deconfig phpmyadmin but problem still persists.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

I also tried to change the password

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

I have googled and found `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` on changing this file would do the trick suggestion needed what change should i make in config file.

Any solution is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using the root user, please check to see if the following line is in your config.inc.php file for the phpMyAdmin installation.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: i have found config.inc.php in /etc/phpmyadmin config.inc.php